# Issue on cursor moving keys "hjkl" in jVi (NetBeans 7.2 under Mac OS 10.7.4)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I'm using jVi with the default setting in NetBeans 7.2. When I keep pressing a moving key (say, `i`), the caret just moves only once (i.e., to the next line), which is supposed to keep moving until I release `i` (the same case as for `j`, `k` and `l`). I've tested jVi in NetBeans 7.2 under Windows 7, and there is no such an issue.

Anyone knows what's wrong with jVi? Or do I have to configure something to make the caret work fine?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this fix it? http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206589

Comment: I uninstalled and installed for several times, and now it works... don't know why. But thanks for the link. I think this issue should be a bug. How can I accept your comment as an answer? @Petesh